# How can I get all lines of output to print from left to right?

Tags: java, string

I am printing out a queue, then I call a method firstToLast and print it again. Then, I call a method lastToFirst and print it again. I want all three lines of output to look nice and neat and print from left to right. The first line does that but the second and third line of output prints top to bottom. How can I get all three lines of output to print the same way.

```
public class QueueNodeRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      QueueNode list = new QueueNode();
      list.enQueue("a");
      list.enQueue("b");
      list.enQueue("c");
      list.enQueue("d");
      list.enQueue("e");
      list.enQueue("f");
      list.enQueue("g");
      list.enQueue("h");
      list.enQueue("i");
      list.enQueue("j");
      QueueListIterator iter = list.listIterator();
      System.out.println("Elements in Queue: "); 
      while (iter.hasNext())
      {
         Object s = iter.next();
         System.out.print(" " + s.toString());
      }
      list.firstToLast();
      System.out.print("\n" + list);
      list.lastToFirst();
      System.out.print("\n" + list);
   }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Elements in Queue: 
 a b c d e f g h i j
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
a

a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove you \n in the System.out.print method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep using

```
while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Object s = iter.next();
        System.out.print(" " + s.toString());
    }
```

To print your list instead of printing using `toString()` method (implicitly called within your `System.out.print()` method).

Comment: Nothing different so far.

Comment: For this to work, you'd need to redefine the iterator too, I believe. At which point, I'd write a method that took the QueueNode as a parameter, then retrieved the iterator and printed them on a single line. Then you can call this method 3 times.